# Go: How to "put" r.FormValue in datastore and how to "get" from datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Example:
1)Rendered a Login Page through template method. Ex.: this is index.html

```
{{ define "title" }}Guestbook{{ end }}
{{ define "content" }}
    <form action="/login" method="post">
      <div><label>UserName : </label><input name="username" type="text" /></div>
      <div><label>Password : </label><input name="password" type="password" /></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="login"></div>
    </form>
{{ end }}
```

2) hello.go file:

```
package main 

import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
)   

var index = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "templates/base.html",
  "templates/index.html",
))
//UserLogin struct is created
type UserLogin struct{
    UserName string
    PassWord string
}    

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    index.Execute(w, nil)    
}


func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    remPartOfURL := r.URL.Path[len("/login/"):]         
    if r.Method == "POST" {          
    http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("First Name: %s", r.FormValue("username")), http.StatusOK)           
    http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Password: %s", r.FormValue("password")), http.StatusOK)          
    }           
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/login/", login)
}
```

In this Example in login(): Able to print the r.FormValue("username") and r.FormValue("password") but how to "put" in datastore and how to "get" from datastore.

Comment: This is now the fourth question you have posted within a short period of time on things that seem to be quite simple. You should probably go and do the App Engine Go tutorial and then ask questions when you have problems that aren't covered by the docs.

Comment: There are many things which are not covered by that document.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://github.com/stephenlewis/eveningwithgo/blob/master/datastore/datastore/datastore.go

**Answer :**

package main

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
  "appengine"
  "appengine/datastore"
)

var index = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
  "templates/base.html",
  "templates/index.html",
))

type cUserLogin struct{
    UserName string
    PassWord string
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
    index.Execute(w, nil)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "handler : ", "\n")
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("cUserLogin")
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        for t := q.Run(c); ; {
            var getuser cUserLogin
            key, err := t.Next(&getuser)
            if err == datastore.Done {
                break
            }
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v: %s %s\n", key, getuser.UserName, getuser.PassWord)
        }

}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {  
        remPartOfURL := r.URL.Path[len("/login/"):] 
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
        if r.Method == "POST" {            
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("First Name: %s", r.FormValue("username")), http.StatusOK)           
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprintf("Password: %s", r.FormValue("password")), http.StatusOK)
            g := cUserLogin{
                UserName: r.FormValue("username"),
                PassWord: r.FormValue("password"),
            }
            key, err := datastore.Put(c, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "cUserLogin", nil), &g)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Written with key %v\n", key)            
        }       

        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello %s!", remPartOfURL)
    }


func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/login/", login)
}
```